# PHP ping Minecraft Server using cURL

Tags: php, curl, minecraft

Helo all,
I have a script that was created for pinging a Minecraft Server using fsockopen. I was wondering if there was a way to convert it to use cURL instead?

Here is the function:

```
function pingserver($host, $port=25565, $timeout=30) {
//Set up our socket
$fp = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
if (!$fp) return false;

//Send 0xFE: Server list ping
fwrite($fp, "\xFE");

//Read as much data as we can (max packet size: 241 bytes)
$d = fread($fp, 256);

//Check we've got a 0xFF Disconnect
if ($d[0] != "\xFF") return false;

//Remove the packet ident (0xFF) and the short containing the length of the string
$d = substr($d, 3);

//Decode UCS-2 string
$d = mb_convert_encoding($d, 'auto', 'UCS-2');

//Split into array
$d = explode("\xA7", $d);

//Return an associative array of values
return array(
    'motd'        =>        $d[0],
    'players'     => intval($d[1]),
    'max_players' => intval($d[2]));
}
```

It seems that this function only works when running on a local server, which is why I want to convert it to cURL so I can run it on a remote server.

Comment: This works fine on a remote server, I just tested it.

Comment: Hmm... I get this error: `Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to xx.xx.xx.xx:25565 (Connection refused) in /home/user/public_html/mc.php on line 6`

Comment: Sounds like you either have some sort of firewall, or, more likely, you are connectin to a bad host/port.

Comment: It turns out it was an issue with my hosting company, they fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

I realise you've resolved your issue but I also had a need for a command-line Minecraft 'ping' so I ported your PHP code to a standalone Perl script and thought I'd share it here in case anyone else needed something similar.  The script uses only core modules so it should work anywhere you have Perl installed.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
##############################################################################
#
# Script:   mcping
#
# Author:   Grant McLean <grant@mclean.net.nz>
#
# Description:
#
# 'ping' a minecraft server to check it's alive
#

use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Socket;
use Pod::Usage;
use Getopt::Long  qw(GetOptions);
use Encode        qw(decode);
use Time::HiRes   qw(gettimeofday tv_interval);

my(%opt);

if(!GetOptions(\%opt, 'help|?')) {
    pod2usage(-exitval => 1,  -verbose => 0);
}

pod2usage(-exitstatus => 0, -verbose => 2) if $opt{help};

my $target = shift or pod2usage(
    -exitval => 1,  -verbose => 0, -message => 'No host specified'
);

my $port = 25565;
if($target =~ /(.*?):(\d+)$/) {
    $target = $1;
    $port   = $2;
}

ping_server($target, $port);

exit 0;


sub ping_server {
    my($host, $port) = @_;

    my $t0 = [gettimeofday];
    my $s = IO::Socket->new(
        Domain   => AF_INET,
        PeerAddr => $host,
        PeerPort => $port,
        Proto    => 'tcp',
    ) || die "$!\n";

    $s->autoflush(1);
    print $s "\xFE";

    sysread($s, my $resp, 256);
    my $elapsed = tv_interval($t0);

    die "Malformed response after connect\n" unless $resp =~ /^\xFF/;

    substr($resp, 0, 3, '');

    $resp = decode('UCS-2', $resp);

    my($motd, $players, $max_players) = split /\x{A7}/, $resp;

    print "Msg of the Day:  $motd\n"
        . "Players Online:  $players\n"
        . "Max Players:     $max_players\n";
    printf "Ping Time:       %5.3fs\n", $elapsed;
}


__END__

=head1 NAME

mcping - 'ping' a minecraft server

=head1 SYNOPSIS

  mcping [options] host-or-ip:port

  Options:

   -?     more detailed help message

=head1 DESCRIPTION

Attempts to connect to a minecraft server on the specified host:port.  On
success, a brief report like this will be printed:

  Msg of the Day:  A Minecraft Server
  Players Online:  2
  Max Players:     10
  Ping Time:       0.175s

If the :port is not specified, the default port number of 25565 will be used.

=head1 OPTIONS

=over 4

=item B<-?>

Display this documentation.

=back

=head1 AUTHOR & COPYRIGHT

This script was written by Grant McLean ( grant@mclean.net.nz ) as a Perl port
of a similar PHP script here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055839/

This script may be freely used, copied and distributed under the same terms as
Perl itself.

=cut
```